# Debugging with templates C++

Tags: c++, templates

This question was inspired by my attempt to implement a hash table in the following code review thread:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113695/hash-table-and-linked-list-implementation-in-c

I am finding that while debugging I am unable to step into functions which make calls to template classes. Moreover, if I set a breakpoint inside a function declared in a template class, the debugger fails to catch it.

I am finding this to be especially problematic when trying to understand large C++ libraries which make heavy use of templating (e.g. Quantlib).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to effectively debug templatized C++ code?

Comment: You could try getting a better debugger.

Comment: Try disabling inlining by your compiler. This can prevent the debugger from stepping into it.

Comment: Which debugger do you use ? Do you try to debug release build ? How do you set breakpoint (problem with IDE integration) ?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse CDT with GDB on MacOS with build settings `-std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0`. I can still catch breakpoints in non-templated codes, just not using templates. @Neil Kirk do you know how to disable inlining in Eclipse? I was unable to find it on google.